# Can’t open Safari on iMac

Tags: safari

Anyone having trouble opening Safari? I tried deleting the plist and restarting but still can’t open Safari.

There was a security update on 24 May but I cant get in to read it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can try

1. Create another user and log in as them. If Safari launches there is something in your old profile causing this problem.
2. Failing that reboot your Mac holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until you see the gray Apple logo. Your Mac is now booting into safe mode. It will take *longer* to boot, so go get a drink and come back in 5 minutes. If Safari launches then there is something that has been installed that is causing Safari to not launch.
3. Download and run the latest Combo Updater for the same version of macOS that you currently have. For the current version of Sierra the combo updater is [here.](http://osxdaily.com/2016/03/22/how-use-combo-update-mac-os-x/)
4. Download a cleaning app (I use [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html)). Quit out of all running apps and run the app. In Onyx click on the Automation Icon and click execute. This will take a while, go have two drinks. When it is done reboot. If Safari works then there was a damaged cache or other file that Onyx cleaned up.

Those should be a good start on fixing it.